# Closing database connection when form is crossed in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, sql, wpf

I am opening database connection using global variable in form constructor and i close it in form Exit button .The problem i am facing is if i cross the form it doesn't close database connection .How i can close connection if form is crossed ?

Comment: for opening the database connection always use "Using".

Comment: for  GlobalVars.conn.Open();     How to use "Using "

Comment: What does "crossed" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better to just check the connection state and then close it.becoz if connection is already closed it will give a exception .Just add the following method it will closed your connection when the form has closed.

```
 protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (sqlConnection.State != System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            sqlConnection.Dispose();
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
        base.OnClosed(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to use a global variable?

It's best to open the database connections only when they are needed and close them as soon as you're done using them. There's no need to keep the connection for longer and the database systems are very good at managing connections nowadays.

If you need to use a global variable, you can override `OnClosing` method:

```
protected override void OnClosing(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // close your connection here
    base.OnClosing(e);
}
```

Comment: Better to check the connection state before it close otherwise it will give you an exception